# Set default segment button to none

Tags: sapui5

So I have a few segmented buttons in my code and they automatically are checked as the first one. Is there anyway to have none checked. I thought it might be something like setselectedbutton but I am unsure.

```
 var oBt1 = new sap.m.SegmentedButtonItem({text :"yes",width : "auto"});
     var oBt2 = new sap.m.SegmentedButtonItem({text :"no",width : "auto"});
     var oBt3 = new sap.m.SegmentedButtonItem({text :"yes",width : "auto"});
     var oBt4 = new sap.m.SegmentedButtonItem({text :"no",width : "auto"});
     var oBt5 = new sap.m.SegmentedButtonItem({text :"yes",width : "auto"});
     var oBt6 = new sap.m.SegmentedButtonItem({text :"no",width : "auto"});

 var oSelectDD = new sap.m.SegmentedButton({items : [oBt1, oBt2]})
     .addStyleClass("bgDarkBack-SB");
     oSelectDD.setSelectedButton(false);
     var oSelectDD2 = new sap.m.SegmentedButton({items : [oBt3, oBt4]})
     .addStyleClass("bgDarkBack-SB");
     var oSelectDD3 = new sap.m.SegmentedButton({items : [oBt5, oBt6]})
     .addStyleClass("bgDarkBack-SB");
```

Answer (score 0):

Created a test button which was never shown and set that as the default selected.

```
         var oBt1 = new sap.m.SegmentedButtonItem({text :"yes",width : "auto"});
     var oBt2 = new sap.m.SegmentedButtonItem({text :"no",width : "auto"});
     var oBt3 = new sap.m.SegmentedButtonItem({text :"yes",width : "auto"});
     var oBt4 = new sap.m.SegmentedButtonItem({text :"no",width : "auto"});
     var oBt5 = new sap.m.SegmentedButtonItem({text :"yes",width : "auto"});
     var oBt6 = new sap.m.SegmentedButtonItem({text :"no",width : "auto"});
     var oBt7 = new sap.m.SegmentedButtonItem({text :"test",width : "auto"});
     var oSelectDD = new sap.m.SegmentedButton({items : [oBt1, oBt2]})
     .addStyleClass("bgDarkBack-SB");
     oSelectDD.setSelectedButton(oBt7);
     var oSelectDD2 = new sap.m.SegmentedButton({items : [oBt3, oBt4]})
     .addStyleClass("bgDarkBack-SB");
     oSelectDD2.setSelectedButton(oBt7);
     var oSelectDD3 = new sap.m.SegmentedButton({items : [oBt5, oBt6]})
     .addStyleClass("bgDarkBack-SB");
     oSelectDD3.setSelectedButton(oBt7);
```